# Ruby Hash inner another Hash is every empty

Tags: ruby, hash

I create a method to group all commits of the a user per month in a Hash:

```
def calculate_month_ranking(commits)
  rank = Hash.new(Hash.new(0))  
  commits.each do |commit_yml|
    commit = YAML.load commit_yml.data

    commit[:commits].each do |local_commit|      
      time = Time.parse(local_commit[:timestamp])
      month = "#{time.month}/#{time.year}"
      rank[month][commit[:user_name]]+= 1
      binding.pry # for debug
    end

  end

  rank  
end
```

But only `rank[month]` have a value, if I call only `rank`, the value is every empty. Why?

```
[1] pry(main)> rank[month]
=> {"user1"=>4, "user2"=>1}
[2] pry(main)> rank
=> {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in the flowing line, assignment is not correct into a hash

```
      rank[month][commit[:user_name]]+= 1
```

I don't know your values, so I am adding here an example you can try out this

Declare the hash as following

```
rank = {}
```

assign values into it as key pair

```
rank.merge!(:month => {:user_name => 'test' })
```

Hear I adding the console output

```
2.0.0-p481 :007 > rank = {}  
=> {} 
2.0.0-p481 :008 > rank.merge!(:month => {:user_name => 'test' })
=> {:month=>{:user_name=>"test"}} 
2.0.0-p481 :009 > rank
=> {:month=>{:user_name=>"test"}} 
2.0.0-p481 :010 > rank[:month]
=>  {:user_name=>"test"}
```

Comment: I need the follow result    {'1'=>{"user1"=>4, "user2"=>1}}

Comment: Simply merge this has to rank variable like  `rank.merge!('1'=>{"user1"=>4, "user2"=>1})`  and get output by putting `rank['1']`